# Does PredictionIO support pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, predictionio

PredictionIO has python SDK, but can I write my template using pyspark?
Most of the templates I have seen are in Java/Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

right now predictionio is running only on java/scala. predictonio has implemented its base version on spark now, but still needs to upgrade. -DAN